# Django If in the article, show all the article titles in the category of this article

Tags: python, django

Hello i need a little help.

I create django cms.

I cant filter category in my post page.

I want, If I'm in the post page, I would like to see other post titles in this category.

Let me explain;
i have three post. post title is like this;

1-bmw3series

2-bmw5series

3-teslaroadster

1st and 2nd post in "bmw" category

3nd post in the "tesla" category

I want to show post categories in the left area. but I want to show post title of that post categorie.

For example, if I'm in bmw5series page, I want only see left category area to bmw3series and bmw5series post titles.

When I use the following code

```
 {% for category in category %}
{% for article in category.get_article %}
<li><a title="{{ article.title }}" href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}">{{ article.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

All post titles are listed... so if im inside bmw5series post just I need to see articles in bmw category....

How do I filter them?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,  get_object_or_404
from .models import Article, Category

def index(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
        "articles": articles,
        "category": category,

         }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def detail(request,slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug = slug)
    category = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request, "detail.html", {"article":article, "category":category,})



def category_detail(request,slug):
    template = "category_detail.html"

    category=get_object_or_404(Category,slug=slug)
    article=Article.objects.filter(category=category)

    context = {
        'article' : article,
    }
    return render(request,template,context)
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name="name")
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True ,related_name='children')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=130)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_article(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(category=self)

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Yazar")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name="Başlık")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name="İçerik")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Oluşturma Tarihi")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Foto Ekle (.jpg .png)")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length = 130)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.title.replace("ı","i"))
        unique_slug = slug
        counter = 1
        while Article.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
            counter += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.get_unique_slug()
        return super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming this

```
{% for category in category %}
{% for article in category.get_article %}
```

To this

```
{% for cat in category %}
{% for article in cat.get_article %}
```

**UPDATE**

If I understand you correctly, whenever you display an article, you want to display the articles of that article's category. If that is correct then you have to change

```
category = Category.objects.all()
```

to

```
category = Category.objects.filter(article=article)
```

Comment: no, its in detail.html page. i want filter categorys in detail post page.

Comment: OK I get it. I think you forgot to add category to the context in category_detail

Comment: If I understand you correctly, whenever you display an article, you want to display the articles of that article's category. If that is correct then you have to change "category = Category.objects.all()" to "category = Category.objects.filter(article=article)"

Comment: oh man its work thank you so much. you are best :) thanks... (please edit your answer i click okay)

Comment: Glad I could help :)